# Showing the tangent space of $SL(n,\mathbb{C})$

Tags: lie-groups, tangent-spaces

> Showing the tangent space of $SL(n,\mathbb{C})=\{A\in GL(n,\mathbb{C}):\det(A)=1\}$ is $S=\{A\in GL(n,\mathbb{C}):\text{trace(A)}=0\}$

I have the definition of tangent space at a matrix $A$ is $T_A(M)=\{X\in M: \exists\gamma:[0,1]\to M,\text{is differentiable}, \gamma'(0)=X,\gamma(0)=A$

So if I take some matrix $B\in T_A(SL(n,C))$ I want to show it has $0$ trace , to show the tangent is contained in my set $S$

But I don't really have anything linking trace of a matrix to its determinant except for $\det(e^A)=e^{Tr(A)}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The map $X\mapsto \exp X$ is a diffeomorphism from a neigborhood of $0_n$ to a neighborhood of $I_n$.  Let $\gamma \colon [0,1[ \to SL(n,\mathbb{C})$, $\gamma(0)= I_n$. For some $\epsilon>0$ we can write $\gamma(t) = \exp \eta(t)$, with $\eta(\cdot)$ smooth, and $\eta(0) = O_n$.  Now $\gamma(t) \in SL(n,\mathbb{C})$ implies $Tr \,\eta(t) = 0$ for  all $t \in [0, \epsilon)$. We have $\gamma'(t) = \exp (\eta(t)) \cdot \eta'(t)$, and $\gamma'(0) = \eta'(0)$ has also trace $0$.

Therefore, the tangent space of $SL(n, \mathbb{C})$ at $I_n$ is $sl(n, \mathbb{C})$, the subspace of $n\times n$ complex matrices with trace $0$.

Note: Here we determined the tangent space of $SL(n,\mathbb{C})$ at $I_n$. At an arbitrary element $A\in SL(n, \mathbb{C})$ it will be $A\cdot sl(n, \mathbb{C})= sl(n,\mathbb{C})\cdot A$.

Comment: Why does $A\cdot sl(n,\mathbb{C})=sl(n,\mathbb{C})\cdot A$? And what is $\eta(t)$?

Comment: both multiplication on the left or right by $A$ invariates $SL(n,\mathbb{C})$ and takes $I$ to $A$, so its derivative ( still mult by $A$, because it's a linear map) takes the tangent space at $I$ to tg space at $A$.   Now $\eta(t) = \exp^{-1}( \gamma(t))$, we know $\exp^{-1}$ is defined and smooth on a nbhd of $I_n$.

Comment: I guess I dont understand because it seems like you defined $\gamma(t)=\gamma(t)$